# Why is my program saying that 5 * 5 is equal to 104126025?

Tags: c++, replit

I created a function to return the result of all the odd numbers in a vector.

```
    int oddProduct(std::vector<int> arr) {
    int sum = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.size(); i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            sum *= arr[i];
            std::cout << " " << arr[i];
            }
         }
    return sum;
    }
```

The function worked with every other vector I inputted and the print statements even show that the elements of the vector I multiply are both equal to 5.
(btw I was using repl.it)

Comment: please post a [mcve]. include input,output and expected output in the question

Comment: `i <= arr.size()` and `arr[i]` is UB.

Comment: btw "the result of all odd numbers" ... result of what? Are you confusing `+` and `*` ? At least `sum` is not a sum

Comment: You would have cleaner code and avoid the bug if you used an iterator instead of an integer index variable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Or range-based for.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was just about to suggest that. It's the best gift to loops ever. :-)

Comment: @MikeCAT I think that using `std::accumulate` with lambda will also be nice. :) `return std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 1, [](auto a, auto b) { return a * (b % 2 ? b : 1); });`

Comment: If you look more closely at examples, you will notice that they say `<`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 3):

`i <= arr.size()`
The legal values of the subscript are 0 through `size-1` inclusive.

Use a range-based `for` statement to avoid the mistake (and the repeated dereferences)

Comment: a range based for loop does not avoid repeated dereferencing, its just hidden, maybe thats what you mean

Comment: btw if thats the whole answer I'd rather look for a duplicate or (what i did) vote to close as typo, just saying

Comment: a range-based for loop will dereference the iterator once and give you a name for that value.

Comment: ok now I understand, but still you can do the same in a non-range based loop, number of dereferences is the same just hidden from the user. Nevermind, just wasnt sure what you mean